# Object deforms when it becomes a child of a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to make a game where you can control a moving platform and you have to catch the falling objects. For the objects to move with the platform once you have caught it, I made the objects a child of the platform. The problem is that when the object rotates once it has become a child of the platform, it deforms.
[In the image you can see that the objects have become a child of the platform. and its rotatation in the z axis has caused it to deform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NFi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the horizontal scaling of <kbd>platform</kbd> is also being applied to all of the descendants of <kbd>platform</kbd>.

Because platform has no ancestors, one solution you can use is to wrap each of the objects into a container that un-does the scaling created by <kbd>platform</kbd>.

Here's how you do that:

1. When an object collides with <kbd>platform</kbd>, create a new gameobject we can call <kbd>container</kbd>.
2. Make <kbd>container</kbd> have a `localScale` that is the inverse of the `localScale` of <kbd>platform</kbd>.
3. Make <kbd>container</kbd> a child of <kbd>platform</kbd>.
4. Make the object a child of <kbd>container</kbd>.

Here's what that might look like in code, attached to <kbd>platform</kbd>:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2d collision)
{
    // collision verification here...

    // 1  
    GameObject container = new GameObject("container");

    // 2
    Vector3 myScale = transform.localScale;
    container.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f/myScale.x, 1f/myScale.y,
            1f/myScale.z);

    // 3
    // use worldPositionStays=false to keep container's local position zero 
    // & no local rotation
    container.transform.SetParent(transform, false);

    // 4
    collision.transform.SetParent(container);

    // disable rigidbody on the object, etc. ...
}
```

This is simple, but if you ever change the scale of <kbd>platform</kbd>, you will need to update the `localScale` of every <kbd>container</kbd> accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw a similar questions but I wasn't able to follow the solution since I'm quite new to unity.